# How to use a variable in place of ID in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div in which id is generated with index like gal1,gal2,gal3,gal4....

```
var clickid="gal" + index;
$('WANT TO PLACE clickid HERE').click();
```

I want to place the clickid variable inside the jquery selector. How to achieve it. This questions looks silly, but im a beginner eager to learn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#" + clickid).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response and help

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$('#' + clickid).click();
```

Since it is an `id`, you need to prepend `#` to it so that jQuery is able to find it out. This is similar to CSS :)

For more info, have a look at:

- [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)