# How to hide an element defined by a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable itemid (which is the id of an element) which I want to hide, but firefox tells me this code is illegal:

```
  $(#(itemid)).hide();
```

Is what I am trying not possible or am I just tring it the wrong way? Also, in terms of debugging, is it possible to use javascript variable in alert boxes?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a variable in place of ID in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599140/how-to-use-a-variable-in-place-of-id-in-jquery)

Comment: For debugging it's easier to use `console.log( whatever );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#' + itemid).hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
  $('#'+itemid).hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
$("#"+itemid).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector syntax is incorrect. Try:

```
$("#" + itemid).hide();
```

**EDIT**

Fixed stupid mistake.

And to answer the second part of your question, yes it is.

```
var someVar = "hello world";
alert(someVar); // displays an alert box with the variable
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do it :

```
var itemid = '';

$('#'+ itemid ).hide();
```