# Setting a jQuery selector as parameter for a javascript-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a variable in place of ID in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599140/how-to-use-a-variable-in-place-of-id-in-jquery)

I have the function called `makeinvisible` and one of the parameters is supposed to be a *jQuery* id selector for an image with `id=testimage`. *JavaScript* does not recognize it as such, hence the image does not become hidden.

```
function makeinvisible (imageid){
    $("#imageid").css("visibility","hidden")
}

$(document).ready(
    makeinvisible("testimage")
)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Also note that you are using `$(document).ready` incorrectly. You are supposed to pass a function, not `undefined` (`makeinvisible` returns `undefined`). Have a look at the tutorial again: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as written is looking for an element with id=imageid.

Try:

```
function makeinvisible (imageid){

    $("#" + imageid).css("visibility","hidden")
 }

$(document).ready(
  makeinvisible("testimage")
)
```

Edit: Your document.ready call is also incorrect. The way you have it written makeinvisible is being executed immediately, not on document ready. It needs to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ makeinvisible("testimage"); });
```